# My PC has access to internet but my laptop not.

Tags: windows-8

I have a PC and a laptop and a modem that has wireless and cable.
in PC everything is OK but in Laptop I can't access the internet and when I try `ping 4.2.2.4` or `ping 8.8.8.8` it shows `

```
Transmit failed. General Failure in Windows 8
```

I mean I can't access to internet with cable or wireless in laptop.
and when I want to renew my IP Address it shows

```
No operation can be performed on Bluetooth Network Connection while it has media disconnected
```

Comment: It sounds like bluetooth is turned off on your laptop.

Comment: First you need to say how you are connecting, then you need to post the output of `ipconfig /all`

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the DHCP service isn't running.

Winkey + R > type "services.msc" > Click "OK"

Find "DHCP Client" in the list, double-click it, set it to "Automatic", and start it.

Because Windows likes being awkward about network stuff, you might not see a difference until after a reboot.

Comment: That won't help if bluetooth is turned off ...

Comment: I think the problem might be that bluetooth is turned on, and is configured in such a way that it is interfering with the "wireless and cable" connections that the OP is trying to establish.